# seperate openstack password from clouds.yaml in dynamic inventory

Tags: ansible, openstack, ansible-inventory

I would like to use clouds.yaml format for configuring connection to my openstack cloud (as opposed to OS_ env vars).. but I want to be able to check my `clouds.yaml` file into version control. So, my password needs to come from *somewhere else* obviously.

I can successfully do this with other openstack modules by simply not including my password in `clouds.yaml`, and then I can inject the password in via the auth parameter, i.e.:

```
.....
  vars:
    os_password: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          6132613866613437333261......
  tasks: 
  - name: "Make heat stack {{state}}"
    openstack.cloud.stack:
      name: "{{stack_name}}"
      state: "{{state}}"
      template: "rke2-heat/{{stack_name}}.yaml"
      auth:
        password: "{{os_password}}"
......
```

My issue, however, is trying to run a subsequent playbook against the infrastructure using dynamic inventory. I have no idea how to do something like the auth parameter. If I include the password explicitly in clouds.yaml, things work. If I remove it, I get the below error, which I just can't figure out what to do with:

```
$ ansible-inventory -i openstack.yaml --graph                                                                   
[WARNING]: Couldn't list Openstack hosts. See logs for details
Invalid input for field 'identity/password/user/password': None is not of type 'string'

Failed validating 'type' in schema['properties']['identity']['properties']['password']['properties']['user']['properties']['password']:
    {'type': 'string'}

On instance['identity']['password']['user']['password']:
    None (HTTP 400) (Request-ID: req-02606d91-2c50-4bdb-934a-bcacc93e85dd)
```

`openstack.yaml` looks like this:

```
---
plugin: openstack.cloud.openstack
expand_hostvars: false
use_hostnames: true
fail_on_errors: true
all_projects: false
```

Ideal solution would be injecting the vault-encrypted password variable into this file.

Answer (score 0):

Put the variable into the *group_vars/all.yml*. Try [*inventory
group_vars/all*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence) first

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all.yaml
---
os_password: !vault |
      $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
      6132613866613437333261......
```

If the plugin doesn't read by default *group_vars* configure *use_extra_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat openstack.yaml
---
plugin: openstack.cloud.openstack
expand_hostvars: false
use_hostnames: true
fail_on_errors: true
all_projects: false
use_extra_vars: true
```

and put the file into the *-e (--extra-vars)* CLI option

```sh
shell> ansible-inventory -i openstack.yaml -e @group_vars/all.yaml --graph
```

This way, you can put the file wherever you want, of course

```sh
shell> ansible-inventory -i openstack.yaml -e @any_path/os_password.yaml --graph
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thanks for taking some time to help.  Unfortunately, the error persists. 
 The problem isn't just how to inject the variable, but the format of the variable itself.  I am not sure how to make the openstack python inventory plugin script aware of the "os_password" variable.  It seems to insist on pulling ALL variables from env vars OR clouds.yaml only.

I feel like this is a clue... is it looking for a hostvar set on localhost or something?  
`instance['identity']['password']['user']['password']`

Comment: The warning is reported by [*cloud_inventory.list_hosts*](https://github.com/openstack/ansible-collections-openstack/blob/master/plugins/inventory/openstack.py#L256). The question is 'Why is the password missing?'. The debugging is out of the scope here. You'll have to isolate the problem on your own. Try setting the breakpoint at the call [*cloud_inventory.list_hosts*](https://github.com/openstack/ansible-collections-openstack/blob/master/plugins/inventory/openstack.py#L252).